# Create View with date in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table data as below 'table 1', would like to create a view as below 'view1' with the table 1, was that possible?

Table 1

| Code | Outletname | Date | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Outlet A | 01/09/2022 | 10 |
| A | Outlet A | 02/09/2022 | 20 |
| B | Outlet B | 01/09/2022 | 30 |
| B | Outlet B | 02/09/2022 | 40 |

View 1

| Date | Outlet A Total | Outlet B Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/09/2022 | 10 | 30 |
| 02/09/2022 | 20 | 40 |

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry already changed

Comment: *"was that possible?"* - yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH totals AS
(  -- get the total info by outlet and date
   SELECT outletname, date, sum(total) as total
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY outletname, date
), dates AS
(  -- get list of all the dates
   SELECT date 
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY date
) -- use left joins to get the results
SELECT dates.date, ja.total as [outlet a total], jb.total as [outlet b total] 
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN totals ja on dates.date = j1.date and outletname = 'Outlet A'
LEFT JOIN totals jb on dates.date = j1.date and outletname = 'Outlet B'
```

Comment: The tick beside the Accepted